# Consuming resources from a React Admin app in another React Admin app

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am trying to setup two projects based on React Admin, where one project "A" acts as the base project and another one "B" consumes resources from the base project and adds its own on top of it.

"A" is made available to "B" by means of "yarn link". To consume resources (i.e. list/edit/view components) from "A", I had to overcome the restriction that imported JSX files are expected to be compiled already using the approach described here: [Sharing source code and libraries in React](https://medium.com/capriza-engineering/sharing-source-code-and-libraries-in-react-bd30926df312)

Everything seems to work nicely, except for i18n. I create the i18n provider in my "B" project, import messages from the "A" project and pass the i18n provider into "B"'s `<Admin>` component, but no translation keys are resolved at runtime.

I have verified that 1. the i18n provider is called and 2. messages are properly imported in "B".

However, when I run "A" alone (with "yarn start" within the "A" project), calls to `translate` end up in Polyglot code. When I run "B" ("yarn start" in the "B" project), calls to `translate` end up in `TranslationContext` which simply returns the key.

Is there anything else needed that I am missing here?

**Update 1** I have also tried to remove the `appLayout` which I currently import from "A". If I rely on the default layout generated by React Admin in "B", the menu items are translated correctly.

**Update 2** The problem seems to boil down to the fact that both "A" and "B" have redux, react-redux, etc. dependencies and they're resolved differently depending on whether "A" or "B" parts are importing them. The issue in general is discussed [here](https://medium.com/@penx/managing-dependencies-in-a-node-package-so-that-they-are-compatible-with-npm-link-61befa5aaca7) and I've found interesting bug reports in that regard [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6027) or [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/675). Unfortunately I have failed to find a working solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be resolved when I add a webpack alias for `react-admin`, to avoid that it's resolved once via `A/react-admin` and once via `B/react-admin`.

Since I am using `customize-cra`, this meant enhancing my `config-overrides.js` like so:

```
var fs = require ('fs');
var resolveFrom = require('resolve-from');
const {
    override,
    babelInclude,
    addWebpackAlias
} = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = function (config, env) {
    return Object.assign(config, override(
        // this part was required to be able to work with uncompiled JSX from the "A" library:
        babelInclude([
            path.resolve('src'),
            fs.realpathSync('node_modules/A/src')
        ]),
        // this part was added to resolve the issue:
        addWebpackAlias({
            ['react-admin']: resolveFrom(path.resolve('node_modules'), 'react-admin')
        })
    )(config, env))
}
```

Admittedly, I was more expecting needing aliases for `redux` or `react-redux`, rather than for `react-admin`, and I don't yet understand why this causes the described issues with translation. If someone has some more detailed information on this, I would appreciate a comment! For the time being, I'll move on and hope that interaction between "A" components and "B" components will work flawlessly.

Comment: I had to do the same for `@material-ui/core` because the UI was messed up in the production build, caused likely but two separate classNameGenerators. Updated `config-overrides.js` like so: `addWebpackAlias({ ['react-admin']: path.resolve('./node_modules/react-admin'), ['@material-ui/core']: path.resolve('./node_modules/@material-ui/core') })`